# mongodb - i cannot update with $pushAll and simple assignment at the same time

Tags: mongodb

the following fails:

```
db.test.update({_id:102},{$pushAll:{our_days:["sat","thurs","frid"]}, country:"XYZ"}, {upsert:true})
```

error message:  `"Invalid modifier specified: country"`

The correct way seems to be:

```
db.test.update({_id:102},{$pushAll:{our_days:["sat","thurs","frid"]}, $set:{country:"XYZ"}}, {upsert:true})
```

So is it the case that I cannot mix modifiers like "$pushAll" with simple assignments like field:value, in the same update document? Instead I have to use the $set modifier for simple assignments?

Is there anything in the docs that describes this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `db.test.update({_id : 1}, {country : 1})` will just change the **whole** document to country = 1 and thus removing everything else.

So most probably mongo being smart tells you: You want to update specific element and at the same time to remove everything (and that element as well) to substitute it with country = 1. Most probably this is not what you want. So I would rather rise an error.

Regarding the documentation - I think that the best way is to reread [mongodb update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/).